# Правильная передача аргументов в функцию go-mysql-driver

Tags: mysql, golang

Использую [`go-sql-driver/mysql`](https://github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql) для взаимодействия с БД.

Для соединения необходимо передать имя/пароль/бд, как обычно:

```
...
db, err := sql.Open("mysql", "user:password@/db")
...
```

Вопрос: как правильно передать имя/пароль/бд не напрямую, а в виде аргументов?

Следующий вариант не работает:

```
db, err := sql.Open("mysql", ("%s:%s@/%s", mysql_user, mysql_passwd, mysql_db))
```

Comment: [fmt.Sprintf](https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/#Sprintf)?

Comment: Открою тебе страшную тайну, строки можно конкатенировать, простым языком складывать =)

Comment: @Oma прямо как в моем любимом питоне,а я не знал :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
db, err := sql.Open("mysql", mysql_user+":"+mysql_passwd+"@/"+mysql_db)
```

Comment: Кстати, а кроме конкатенации, есть еще способ?

Answer (score 2):

Есть же стандартная библиотека fmt:

```
import "fmt"
//...
db, err := sql.Open("mysql", fmt.Sprintf("%s:%s@/%s", mysql_user, mysql_passwd, mysql_db))
```

Answer (score 0):

Это работает для меня:

```
var sqlname = "mysql"
var user = "user"
var password = ""
var address = "127.0.0.1"
var port = "3306"
var dbname = "dbname"
db, err := sql.Open(sqlname, fmt.Sprintf("%s:%s@tcp(%s:%s)/%s", user, password, address, port, dbname))
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]